# WSO2 Identity Server and WSO2 API Management in Azure

Tags: azure, wso2, azure-storage, wso2-cloud, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to setup WSO2 Identity Server and WSO2 API Management in Microsoft Azure??

If it is, can someone help me how?? Need some advice and direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to follow [WSO2 Identity Server](https://github.com/wso2/product-is) and [Installation Prerequisites](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Installation+Prerequisites).

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You have to add MS Azure as a federated authenticator in WSO2 Identity Server. Please refer this [blog](http://shanakaweerasinghe.blogspot.com/2015/08/add-microsoft-azure-as-federated.html).